# How to get a cookie (jquery.cookie.js) from any domain?

Tags: jquery, cookies

http://jsfiddle.net/YdPPq/3/

I'm working locally, but I feel this should still work.

How do I get the cookie that's on another domain?

and then write back to that domain, but have it work cross domain?

thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't touch cookies from other domains. This is a security feature built into browsers.

Comment: What if I'm on a subdomain - this is a project for work - so I'm trying to get the values

Answer (score 3):

Any browser that lets you view cookies that are specifically set for other domains poses a huge security risk for it's users. Cookies can store sensitive information such as session keys, which can be used to fake logins to other websites.

If you have **set** the cookie yourself, you can set it to be used by any domain if you wish.

Cookies also work for subdomains. For example you can set a cookie to allow access from `example.com`, you can read this from `admin.example.com` and from `www.example.com`, but if it is set for `www.example.com`, you will not be able to read it from `admin.example.com`.